# Particle & Fluid Simulation: Where to learn?

Tags: raytracing, rasterizer, fluid-sim, particles

Where can I learn about particle and fluid simulation? Is there a good book available?  I want to couple volume rendering with fluid/particle simulation to be able to finally render smoke and ocean with foam etc. Is there a chapter in PBRT on it?

Comment: Although recommendations are off topic on the main site (as they are on nearly every Stack Exchange site), you are welcome to discuss recommendations in [chat].

Answer (score 1):

PBRT handles only the rendering part, not the simulation part. There are several books out on game physics that handle fluid simulation, the one on my bookshelf is [David Eberly's "Game Physics".](https://www.crcpress.com/Game-Physics/Eberly/p/book/9780123749031)

Comment: Could you link the other several books?